# C# like XML documentation for existing C++ types from within Visual Studio

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, intellisense, msdn

I'm a C# developer. I got very used to C# intellisense, when I want to learn  little about class's members or method's parameters I can read their XML documentation right from Visual Studio if I want more information I just press F1 and head straight to msdn.

I recently started with C++. What drives me nuts is that there is no such documentation for types/members/macros/parameters/etc... (standard library & win api) so if I want to read what each member or parameter mean I need to visit msdn.

So my question: is there any way or maybe an extension that could provide the same comfortable of C# intellisense? Maybe something to fetch the documentation right from msdn and display it in the intellisense popup window?

Comment: It makes sense that in a Microsoft environment you can access documentation for code written by Microsoft easily.
You can 'F1' a lot of the standard library stuff and the Windows API, but not everything from the C++ language is on MSDN.

Comment: You're right, I only ask about the standard library and win api, I'll update my question

Comment: Have you looked into VS2015? Articles suggest that what they added for C++ will do what you want: See: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2015/04/29/single-file-intellisense-and-other-ide-improvements-in-vs2015.aspx and see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms177226.aspx